# ember-cli-eslint error build passes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, eslint, ember-cli-addons

In an Ember application, I'm trying to switch from jshint to eslint. I've followed the readme for https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint. Everything seems to work when I run "ember test", except when there is an eslint error the build will still pass. I see the eslint error in the console output, but the build will say "ok" when it is done and all the unit tests have passed. How do I get the build to fail if there is an eslint error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the default approach to this changed in 1.5.0 of ember-cli-eslint as described in this issue and the corresponding PR: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint/issues/66

Looks like you have the option of switching the testGenerator function around to one of your own choosing however, so you should've able to pass one in to replace the default behavior if you want to. Might make upgrades to the extension a bit more fragile though ...